# Auto CC all outgoing mail

Tags: gmail, automation

Is there a way to auto CC to a specific email adress all outgoing emails from a Gmail account?

I tried doing it with a filter but I don't have the option of CC. I know there is a script for GreaseyMonkey but it only works on Firefox and I need this to work on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) extension for Chrome. It will allow you to install GM scripts (according to extension detail, it supports all GM_* functions).

I use the extension personally and I've not had any issues up to this point.

Comment: I installed Tampermonkey, but the Auto CC/BCC script for Greasemonkey is not working (i get this error saying that tampermonkey does not support some greasemonkey scripts)... thanks anyway!

Comment: The AutoBCC script for Tamper/Greasemonkey does not work with the new editor.