# How to get my sent mail included in my inbox?

Tags: gmail

I've recently started using my inbox as my primary view in Gmail. But I have one major complaint: sent mails do not bump threads into my inbox.

How can I make it so all sent mails go in my inbox?

Comment: I don't see how, since Gmail filters act on messages as they come in.

Comment: However, perhaps you can automatically CC yourself. [Auto CC all outgoing mail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26959)

Comment: Related: [Sent Item filters in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30523) | [How do you create a filter in Gmail that will apply to all composed/sent messages?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35657)

Comment: @AlEverett: The AutoBCC script does not anymore with the new editor.

Comment: Well... Bummer.